# LabelEncoder().fit_transform gives me negative values?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, one-hot-encoding, label-encoding

Hei,

I have different city names in the column "City" in my dataset. I would love to encode it using LabelEncoder(). However, I got quite frustrating results with negative values

`df['city_enc'] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df['City']).astype('int8')`

The new city_enc column gives me values from -128 to 127. I do not understand why LabelEncoder().fit_transform gives me negative values? I expect that it would give value from 0 to (n-1). Can anyone explain this to me?

Best regards,
Lan Nguyen

Comment: How many unique values are in the `City` column? If you have more than 128, then you will obtain negative values. Simply drop the `astype('int8')` conversion or use a larger datatype, such as `int16` or `int32`.

Comment: Thanks so much, @AlexandruDinu. I have changed it to int16. City name has 1801 unique values. Now it works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most certainly this is because you are trying to encode more than 128 (0 ... 127) different cities (you can check this with `len(df['City'].unique())`).

When you then force a conversion to `int8` you end up with negative values in order to ensure that all the labels are distinct. With `int8` you have 256 different values (-128 ... 127). For example, if you encode 129 different values as `int8`, you will use all of the 0 ... 127 positive values, and one item will be assigned the label `-128`.

One simple solution is to just drop the `astype('int8')` conversion:

```py
df['city_enc'] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df['City']) # defaults to 'int64'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the conversion to type `int8` which can only encode values -128 to 127. Check this example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'City': [i for i in range(129)]
})

le = LabelEncoder()
```

Case 1:

```py
df['City_enc1'] = le.fit_transform(df['City'])
print(df['City_enc1'])

>>> 0        0
1        1
2        2
3        3
4        4
      ... 
124    124
125    125
126    126
127    127
128    128
Name: City_enc1, Length: 129, dtype: int64
```

Case 2:

```py
df['City_enc2'] = le.fit_transform(df['City']).astype('int8')
print(df['City_enc2'])

>>> 0        0
1        1
2        2
3        3
4        4
      ... 
124    124
125    125
126    126
127    127
128   -128
Name: City_enc2, Length: 129, dtype: int8
```

See that because of the conversion in the second case, `LabelEncoder` has to use negative values.

Better would be to not convert at all or choose `int16` or above as alternatives.